# What could cause overflow menu items to be truncated / ellipsized for no apparent reason?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I am seeing a strange issue come up in our Android app, specifically on the Moto X with 4.4.

On the preference activity, all of the titles have the first 8 characters truncated at the beginning with ellipses. This is also occurring in the overflow menu, and various other (apparently) random TextViews throughout the app, all of which occurrences have the first 8 characters truncated. For example, I have an overflow item called "Delete." This should in no way be truncated, and isn't truncated on any of my devices except the Moto X. What appears on the overflow item is just "...".

What is strange, is that if I select one of the overflow items that is truncated, the text then returns to how it should be. This behavior also occurs in the preference screen as well.

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this? I haven't been able to reproduce it on another device, nor in another app on the same device. I'm not sure what code could be relevant to share for this, as I am just referencing plain, old strings in my strings.xml, and I don't control the code over the overflow menu items' nor the preference screen titles' ellipses.

Comment: That sounds singularly bizarre. Which action bar are you using? (API Level 11 native? AppCompat? ActionBarSherlock? something else?)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed bizarre. Native action bar. minSdk 14. Completely lost on this one.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce it on an emulator running 4.3(? or whatever the X has), then for the moment I'd chalk it up as something screwy with that device. I don't even know *how* you ellipsize text in a `Preference`, let alone how it might be happening accidentally. The only thing that I can suggest is that if you can create a small standalone project that reproduces the problem, upload it somewhere, so we can take a peek at it.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this is down to the new handling of textviews wrapping since kitkat. Automatic reflow of text is disabled on Kitkat and this looks like an exact example of text not reflowing and instead just truncating.